# I am trying to remove special characters but keep spaces and _ not working PHP

Tags: php

This is my code. I am using regex to check when creating a folder it does not contain special characters but allow spaces and underscores in the name. This code does not work but i cannot find the reason why. Please help me

```
if (preg_replace("/[^\w ]+/", "", $filename))
{
  echo 'A file name can not contain The Following Characters: \ / : * ? " < > | %';
}else{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace` when you want to check? what about `preg_match`?

Comment: You don't define what "special" means for you, you don't provide sample input and you don't explain how it doesn't work. This looks like an assignment rather than a question.

Comment: Its a question not an assignment I need to let the user create a folder which can contain spaces and _ but not special characaters in the name of the folder

Comment: You should use a whitelist of allowed characters, and not a blacklist of disallowed characters. In this respect, your code does not match your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`strpbrk()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) to search a string for any of a set of characters.

```
if (strpbrk($directoryName, "\\/?%*:|\"<> ") === FALSE) {
    /* $directoryName is legal; doesn't contain illegal character. */
}
else {
    /* $directoryName contains at least one illegal character. */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With preg_replace you replace the instances with something, from the [php.net documentation](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

> **preg_replace()**: Searches subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with replacement.

You want the [preg_match function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) which returns a boolean on if there was a match.

> **preg_match()**: Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Your using `preg_replace` you should be using `preg_match`

`preg_replace` will return the string which will always be true, unless everything has been removed

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9%\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $Your_String);
```